# call postrgresql function: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883

Tags: function, jpa, hibernate-mapping, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to call a pg fuction by javax.persistence.EntityManager but I get the [pg error 42883](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/errcodes-appendix.html). I checked pg search_path and db user grants but all seems ok (in sql editor, it works).
Below the main snippets. Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

#JunitTest:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
@Transactional("herokuTransactionManager")
public void call_performanceentitybyqualitycode_fb() {

    String json = "{\"quality_code\":\"ALL\", \"sections\":\"ALL\"}";
    
    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("myexamplefunction")
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).setParameter(2, json)
            
    ;
    List<Object[]> obj = query.getResultList();
    assertNotNull(obj);
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(obj));
}
```

#Configuration Bean:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:db.hibernate.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "poc.mule.repository.heroku", entityManagerFactoryRef = 
herokuEntityManager",transactionManagerRef = "herokuTransactionManager")
public class PersistenceHerokuConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Value("${heroku.datasource.username}")
private String username;
@Value("${heroku.datasource.password}")
private String password;
@Value("${hibernate.connection.driver_class}")
private String driver;
@Value("${heroku.datasource.url}")
private String url;

private static final String ENTITY_FOLDER = "poc.mule.entity.heroku";

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean herokuEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(herokuDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(ENTITY_FOLDER);

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
            env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
            env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.default_schema",
            env.getProperty("hibernate.default_schema"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
            env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
}

@Bean
public DataSource herokuDataSource() {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setSchema("test");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager herokuTransactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
            herokuEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

#db.hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
hibernate.default_schema=test
hibernate.show_sql=true

heroku.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxxx:5432/xxxx
heroku.datasource.username=xxxxxx
heroku.datasource.password=xxxxxxxxx

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Why a `StoredProcedureQuery`? A function can be called with a regular select statement: `select myexamplefunction(?,?)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried @Query(value = "select myexamplefunction(:i_input);", nativeQuery = true) Object myexamplefunction(@Param("i_input") String json); ---- Same error. I need to return a cursor so I verified that my test works on public schema functions but not on test schema

Comment: Found the problem: test switched on wrong peristence unit (project has two persistence units). Solved adding @PersistenceContext(unitName = "heroku")
 @Qualifier("herokuEntityManager")
 private EntityManager em;